# How to exact numbers from an array in a cell

Tags: arrays, count, nested, extract

In one of the columns of my df, the values in the cell are reported as an array (e.g. `[1,2,3,4,8]`) as opposed to being just single numbers. This is because the question was a "select all that apply" question.

However, when I try to count how many of each number occurs, I am not able to do so because these numbers are nested within a list. How can I extract the numbers so that I am able to count them?

For example:

```
row 1: [1,2,3,4,8]
row 2: [3]
row 3: [1,2,3,4]
```

I want to be able to run a statement such as: `nrow(df[df$column == 1,])` that will count all of the occurrences of the number `1`.  So, in this case, the output would be `2`, but right now it says `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using base R:

```
# set up data
df <- as.data.frame(c('[1,2,3,4,8]', '[3]', '[1,2,3,4]'))
colnames(df) <- c('data')

# strip off starting and ending brackets
stripped <- substr(df$data, 2, nchar(df$data)-1)

# split each row by comma
split <-  strsplit(stripped, ',')

# flatten the list of numbers to a vector
numbers <- unlist(split)

# view table of frequency of each number
table(numbers)
```

output:

```
numbers
1 2 3 4 8 
2 2 3 2 1
```

getting count of a single number

```
# view count of a single number
length(which(numbers == '8'))
```

output:

```
[1] 1
```